# Выдаёт неверные значения c++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имею подобный txt-файл . Для перенесения данных в два массива написал такой код:

```
vector<double> a;
vector<int> v;
double at;
int vt;
ifstream ff("var13.txt");
while (ff >> at >> vt)
{
    a.push_back(at);
    v.push_back(vt);
}
```

Однако мною было замечено, что если использовать для вывода цикл

```
for (auto i:a)
    cout << a[i] << "    " << v[i] << endl;
```

То на экран выведется такое содержимое:

```
14.078    10
14.078    10
13.29     7
```

и так далее, что является неверным.

В то же время, если использовать для вывода цикл

```
for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();i++)
   cout<< a[i] <<"    "<< v[i] <<endl;
```

То содержимое выведется верное. Не понятно, почему вывод получается неккоректным.

В своей программе я так же буду обращаться к элементам этих массивов, и теперь не понятно, могу ли я это делать переменными типа int, и придется ли их переводить в (size_t)

Прошу помощи в данном вопросе

Comment: Пока что не видно ничего... не могли бы вы выложить где-то именно сам ваш файл с данными и минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода - может, ошибка при выводе массива?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в:

```
for (auto i:a)
   cout << a[i] << "    " << v[i] << endl;
```

в `i` записывается значение элементов вектора, и  это равносильно, что написать:

```
for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();i++)
   cout<< a[a[i]] <<"    "<< v[a[i]] <<endl;
```

что наверняка не является вашим намерением, и вполне может привести к попытке вывода элемента за пределы вектора

Answer (score 0):

Цикл `for (auto i:a)` перебирает значения из массива a. Соответственно i имеет тип double и последовательно принимает значения: 14,602
14,227
13,619 ... 
и так далее.

a[i] на первой итерации будет то же самое, что и a[14], то есть 14,078. Ну и так далее.

Рекомендую обращать внимание на warnings, наверняка там есть предупреждение, что в строке `cout << a[i] << "    " << v[i] << endl;` имеется сужающее преобразование из double в int.